# Accessing static resources in Spring Boot when url is not root

Tags: css, spring-security, spring-boot

Sorry if this has already been asked before but everything I have tried has not worked. The problem I have is that my static resources are not being loaded when the url is not root, i.e if the url is localhost:8080/users the css files load fine but if I try load the css files for localhost:8080/users/1 or any other url after users the static files don't load. My static files are in resources/static/public/css.

I know it's probably something stupid. Thanks in advance.

My webConfig class:

```
  @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                            "/home",
                            "/error",
                            "/signup",
                            "/forgot-password",
                            "/reset-password/*",
                            "/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    //.defaultSuccessUrl()
                    .permitAll().and()
                .rememberMe().key(rememberMeKey).rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
}
```

MvcConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Updated ***
Header file

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./public/images/favicon/logo.png"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/style.css"/>
```

Footer:

```
 <script src="./public/lib/bootstrap-3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./public/js/home.js"></script>
<script src="./public/js/webcam.js"></script>
<script src="./public/js/recordVideo.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is likely in the way you include the resources in your templates. Please post that.

Comment: Just added them there! Cheers. Im also deploying this to tomcat just in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are serving your static assets from file relative (./) paths. They become inaccessible when you serve files from deeper in your directory structure.

Use site relative paths: (/). Eg:

```
" /public/..."
```

Our embed a complete url to your server.